# Rails undefined method `fetch' for "\\# PostgreSQL. Versions 7.4 and 8.x are supported.":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, assets

When I run 'RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile' on my production machine I get this error:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/ruby /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
undefined method `fetch' for "\\# PostgreSQL. Versions 7.4 and 8.x are supported.":String
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:35:in `resolve_string_connection'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in `spec'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:in `establish_connection'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:88:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `block in on_load'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `each'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `on_load'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:80:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/map7/pais/config/environment.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/application.rb:305:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.16/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:93:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.16/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/ruby /...]
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:54:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `sh'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:82:in `ruby'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `ruby'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.16/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.16/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.16/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

I've tried updating the 'pg' gem. I can compile assets on my development & staging servers. The production machine was working on the last deploy (7 days ago) and I haven't changed any database related config.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"\\# PostgreSQL. Versions 7.4 and 8.x are supported."` looks like a mangled first line of a database.yml file.

Was the `\\` accidentally added to that line? `#` denotes a normal comment.

Comment: Yep it was a \# at the start of my database.yml file, how I overlooked that file I don't know. Thanks

Comment: @map7 does that solves the problem. I guess it should if you remove it. Moreover, i dont think you can even do `rails c`.

Comment: I had the same problem when starting a Rails project on Codenvy.  Was totally confused until I found this post.  My database.yml file has a line that needed to be deleted/commented out. All it took....